# Error in mice imputation multilevel data: boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

Tags: imputation, r-mice, multi-level

I am trying to impute a multilevel data set with students in classes.
When I run my analysis for one out of several imputed variables I receive the error: boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular') What does it mean or how can I handle it? In my predictor matrix I defined my level 2 cluster as pred1.1 [,"s_id_K"] <- -2  Does the error mean that the particular variable does not differ between my classes? How could I resolve this problem? Is it by the method or imputation matrix in mice?